# read in xls file in r from business objects

Tags: r, excel, xls, readxl

I have downloaded a xls file from business objects and want to read it in R.
I have tried several options, the easiest one being:

```
library("readxl")
txt=read_excel("file.xls", sheet = 2)
```

The problem is that it gives me an empty tibble. However, if I open the xls file, do absolutely nothing, save it and try again, it does work! 
Since I need to make a data pipeline I want it to work right away without this weird workaround. 
Any idea what the problem is? My own thoughts went to some kind of security, read-only, adminstrator permission kind of property but couldn't figure it out.

Kind regards!
Piet

Comment: You could try `gdata::read.xls` and see if you get the same issue.

Comment: I tried that indeed and got the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I always try to avoid importing .xls files due to such problems. Where possible I always import it as a .csv file. Depending on the structure of the .xls file, however, this is not always possible or may be extra work if you have many tabs within your .xls file.

If possible, export your .xls as an .csv file and then import it using `read.table()` or use a function through the many available packages such as `data.table` or `tidyverse`.

Comment: Sure, avoiding xls and using csv or alike would help. But this does not address the question and hence is not an answer unless you show how to get the data as, for example, csv from its source.

Comment: Yes I can manually go into the xls file, save it again (don't even need to change its extension) and then it works. But since I need to be doing this lots of times I'm trying to work around the problem with R code rather than manual work. 
read.table() doesn't seem to work for xls files. Neither does fread.
Is there anything else I can try. Perhaps in the folder permissions or something like that?

Comment: @Tino workarounds are also answers. I believe my answer is a straightforward and easy solution. So you want me to explain how to save a .xls file aa .csv in Excel?

Comment: @PietHein what do you mean with lots of times? Many different .xls files / tabs? As mentioned below, fread or read.table does not work with .xls extension files. You have to save as ‘.csv’ file first.

Comment: Lots of times as in every day I need to download the file (which has 3 tabs) and run the checker that I'm writing for the next 7 months. It should be a one go pipeline without having to download, open the file, save as, open r and then run it. The only other extension I can download the file in is .pdf which works with pdf_text() but messes up the formatting.

Comment: @PietHein ok, I understand. Did you try the ‘XLConnect’ or  ‘xlxs’ as alternatives? I saw you already tried through gdata.

Comment: I did. The XLConnect with this code:
loadWorkbook("r110.xls",create=TRUE)
gives me the following error: 
Error: RuntimeException (Java): Unexpected record type (org.apache.poi.hssf.record.HyperlinkRecord)
It indicates that something is weird about my excel file but it does not specify what. When I open, save and close the xls file (which makes it work for the read_excel() function) it gives me a new error:
Error: NoSuchMethodError (Java): org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getNumCellStyles()I
Which is why I kinda abandoned this one..

Comment: read.xlsx("r110.xls",sheetIndex =2) gives me this error: 
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected record type (org.apache.poi.hssf.record.HyperlinkRecord)
Which didn't even give me a result in google so I abandoned that one too..

Comment: @PietHein Your error may have to do with your Java. Have you updated Java and what version are you running? Other issue, but similar problem was described here: https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer/issues/42

Comment: I did also update java yesterday to no avail. Current version is: version 8 update 191 (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
R also refers to the newest version: 
library(rJava)
.jinit()
.jcall("java/lang/System", "S", "getProperty", "java.runtime.version")
 "1.8.0_191-b12"

The error messages I just posted are from this morning with the latest version

Comment: @PietHein do you manually download all the files? This may be a stupid question but are you sure it has .xls extension? This issue describes the same issue as you have, including that it works when they save it in excel. https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/480

Comment: Damn I had my hopes up for a bit but it's really not an html but an excel 97-2003 worksheet with .xls extension. I tried to read it as an html just in case like in the github post but it turns up as 20 lines of gibberish instead of the 50k lines that are in the file.
I do have to manually download the files using the business objects interface to access the database

Comment: @PietHein that is too bad. Do you also have the issue if you work with only one sheet instead referring to the 2nd, as what you do in your example script?

Comment: If I refer to the first sheet it's the same problem. If I delete sheets so I'll just end up with 1 however, I'll have to save the document and then the problem is fixed somehow. But if I don't do anything and just save the problem is also solved but I had hoped for a cause/solution to go around this lol. I guess I'll just keep manually saving the document every time. Thanks a lot for the effort though!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much, but it's a bug with the package. You can go down to readxl 1.0.0 and it works.

GitHub issue mentioning dropping versions: https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/474

How to go down to the version you want: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages

Answer (score -1):

You can use the package `data.table` that provides a very easy and faster method to read and write `.csv` or `.xls/.xlsx` with the `fwrite` and `fread` functions. It package already has an automatic separate detector.

You cand find more information about this package [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.11.6).